# Show forbidden icon on hover when ng-click is not available

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

I know that this can be made for an icon. I'm wondering if it is possible for a span as it is in my case.

```
<span ng-click="!$ctrl.clicked && $ctrl.doSomething()" 
      ng-class="$ctrl.clicked ? 'unclickable' : 'clickable'">
      Click here!
</span>
```

This is my code so far, it uses `ng-class` to change the color of the text if it is clickable or not.

What I want to add is to have a forbidden-icon when I hover over the text. Is it possible in this case? (without changing from span to other)

Comment: yes, its possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css you should be able to add a "cursor: not-allowed;" in the "unclickable" class.

Answer (score 2):

```
.unclickable {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Or whichever [cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional `ng-class` like this:

```
ng-class="{true: 'ClassA', false: 'ClassB'}[condition]"
```

For your code, change `ng-class` with this part of code:

```
ng-class="{true: 'unclickable', false: 'clickable'}[$ctrl.clicked]"
```